# Projector-Camera Extrinsic Calibration?

Tags: python, opencv

Is there any functionality to calibrate a laser stripe / pattern projector with the Camera? Any ideas how I can modify the existing framework of calibrating two cameras to extend it to one camera and a projector?

Comment: search for structured light or kinect v1. The general idea is, that the projector's image can be seen as a camera image (projector pixel == camera pixel) and the real camera is seeing the projector image with sone disparity

Comment: By `That the projector's image can be seen as a camera image (projector pixel == camera pixel) ` do you mean that the laser stripe is visible on the image taken by the camera, and this camera is viewing the image with some offset which is the disparity?

Comment: the offset is disparity, yes. But the projector image itself is the reference, since if the projector was a camera in addition to being a projector, it would see exactly the same pattern that was projected, without any offsets.